# Skip adding property to database

Tags: c#, winforms

How to skip adding property to database? I could only find for Entity framework -> [NotMapped]. What would be same thing for Win Forms application?

Comment: Please include the code chunk where you're encountering the error. It would be easier to solve this way.

Comment: EntityFramework is an ORM for databases, WinForms is a UI framework (nothing to do with databases in first place)

Comment: Just do not use "model" classes for Winforms logic